# How to pass parameters dynamically from JSP to Action class?

Tags: jsp, struts2

On Struts2, I have a JSP displaying some articles depending on the List object. 
What articles are displayed is always changing.

Then, how can I pass them to another Action class?
if they have fixed names, mapping would be easy, but they doesn't.

I deal with any ListArray, not only ListArray, so  tag would now seem to be enough.
Is there any nice way to pass dynamically changing parameters to an Action class as collection(Map,ListArray,etc.)?

Comment: I don't really understand the question. In any case, using a map sounds like it might be the easiest, with a less-preferred option bring accessing the parameters directly via ParameterAware.

Comment: what exactly is your issue? i believe even if the articles are dynamic they must have some sort of id associated with it or they are like random ?